# How to verify url without navigating to page in cypress

Tags: javascript, angularjs, automation, navigation, cypress

I want to check the url without visiting the actual page, basically application is on angularJS and navigates using ng-click method ($state.go). I have seen too many documentations of cypress stub and intercept but haven't found any thing regarding this type of problem statement.

I have tried below

```
cy.window().then((win) => {
  cy.stub(win, 'open').as('redirect');
});
cy.get('@redirect').should(
  'be.calledWith',
  'myUrl'
);
```

but this is use for new tab, i need it for same tab, can anyone help regarding this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: So you want to check the url of a click method without any actions on the element, correct?

Comment: yes correct, just need to verify it is opening correct url on clicking, no need to open that link

Comment: No need, or must not? It's easier if you allow the navigation, you can then just check `cy.location()`

Comment: My initially thought was to check for href. Fody's comment will have the entire url.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the navigation, it does depend on how the app does it.

One example for stubbing `window.location.replace` is shown here

[Deal with window.location.replace](https://glebbahmutov.com/blog/cypress-tips-and-tricks/#deal-with-windowlocationreplace)

Can also be used with `window.location.href`.

```js
it('replaces', () => {
  cy.on('window:before:load', (win) => {
    win.__location = {
      replace: cy.stub().as('replace')
    }
  })

  cy.intercept('GET', 'index.html', (req) => {
    req.continue(res => {
      res.body = res.body.replaceAll(
        'window.location.replace', 'window.__location.replace')
    })
  }).as('index')

  cy.visit('index.html')
  cy.wait('@index')
  cy.contains('h1', 'First page')
  cy.get('@replace').should('have.been.calledOnceWith', 'https://www.cypress.io')
})
```

This is more complicated than a simple stub, because window.location can't be stubbed (a security measure in the browser).

Gleb Bahmutov shows how to intercept the page load to get around the problem.